# A matching X25519 public from non-clamped Ed25519-public and Ed25519-secret

Tags: public-key, ed25519, x25519

Given an Ed25519 key pair, can you think of any way to get to the same X25519 public key from the Ed25519 secret as from the *non-clamped(!)* Ed25519 public key?

```
Ed25519 secret
    \=> Ed25519 non-clamped public
            \=> X25519 public (transported)

                v^ should match 

            /=> X25519 public (generated)
    /=> X25519 secret (transported)
Ed25519 secret
```

My [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77390992/derive-same-x25519-public-from-either-ed25519-public-or-ed25519-secret) has some libsodium calls for further illustration.

---

What about the inverse:

```
X25519 secret
    \=> X25519 public (generated)
            \=> Ed25519 non-clamped public (transported)

                v^ should match 

            /=> Ed25519 non-clamped public (generated)
    /=> Ed25519 secret (transported)
X25519 secret
```

Comment: **Using the same key for different purposes is not recommended!**. Besides the there is no isomorphism between the twisted Edward curve and Curve25519, they are bi-rationally equivalent means that some finite points are not mapped in forward and backward mappings.

Comment: Also, the Clamping removes the small orders and sets the higher bits to eliminate a possible side-channel attack. Now how can you map $n$ elements to $8n$ elements? The best is to keep it Clamped, and **still not advised** or you need to use exact rules https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/42536/18298

Comment: @kelalaka If you handle $\infty$ in Curve25519, Ed25519 and Curve25519 are isomorphic, I thought.  The birational equivalence works for all Curve25519 points except $\infty$, and to complete the isomorphism you can set $\infty_{\text{Curve25519}} = {(0,1)}_{\text{Ed25519}}$.

Comment: @Myria if you are talking about the clamped yes, otherwise $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$

Comment: Every public key of X25519 constitutes 2 public keys for Ed25519. How are you gonna solve this in your implementation?